# div content exceed viewport height

Tags: html, height, viewport, parallax, exceed

Here's the issue. I'm using a CSS parallax method that I've found here http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/ .

Problem is, I have one section which content exceed the 100% viewport height that all divs are set to. How can I make my div expend in order to show all of its content and not just the viewport height ? The exceeding content in sliding under the next div

Here's an exemple https://codepen.io/Dwoop/pen/LOgLRw?editors=1100

```
.parallax {
height: 500px; /* fallback for older browsers */
height: 100vh; /* standard divs size that cannot expend */
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
-webkit-perspective: 300px;
perspective: 300px;
-webkit-perspective-origin-x: 100%;
perspective-origin-x: 100%;}
```

Why doesn't my first div (#group1) adapt to my inner div height ? Plus here the first div is even smaller than the viewport... I really don't understand how these height settings work.

Any help would do